# Goutte Post JSON or set cookie

Tags: php, html, symfony, goutte

I'm trying to submit a form using Goutte. The form uses jQuery to serialize a form to json and post to an url. After submitting, it updates the browser's cookie.

I either need to:

1. set the cookie manually in Goutte,
2. or send the json post through Goutte so it's cookie jar is updated.

I tried using Goutte's `addContent` method to create a form and then post it, but it's not sent as JSON, just a regular query string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here's a class method that may serve as example for both JSON and URLencoding with Goutte.

```
use Goutte\Client;

class a 
{
   /**
   * abstract the request content-type behind one single method,
   * since Goutte does not natively support this
   * @param string $method HTTP method (GET/POST/PUT..)
   * @param string $url URL to load
   * @param string $parameters HTTP parameters (POST, etc) to be sent URLencoded 
   *                           or in JSON format.
   * @return \Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response
   */
  protected function makeRequest($method, $url, $parameters) {
      $client = new Client();
      if ($this->requestFormat == 'json') {
          return $client->request($method, $url, array(), array(), array('HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'), json_encode($parameters));
      } else {
          return $client->request($method, $url, $parameters);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To set a cookie in Goutte, try this:

```
$client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
```

I believe $cookie is of type `Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie`, so if you check the docs for that you should be able to send a cookie in the form the call needs.

If you wish to load a resource via POST, try this:

```
$client->request('post', $url, $params);
```

I would expect `$params` to be an associative array of values to submit to the JSON operation.